# Relating a child table to multiple parent tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out the best way to relate these tables together. Suppose I have the following tables:

- tblPerson
- tblGroup
- tblResource

Each row in each of these tables can have multiple email addresses associated with them so I would want a separate table and relate it back.

Are there methods to have a single table (tblEmail) relate back to each of the tables. I thought of using a uniqueidentifier field in each of the parent tables and using that as a key in the email table. It would be guaranteed unique. I just wouldn't be able to create a FK in the email table to preserve integrity. That is manageable though.

Is there a fancy way to do this? I am creating these tables in SQL 2008 R2.

Thank you
Karl

Comment: You want many Email records for each Person/Group/Resource record, that much I got. Are you also wanting to create some relation between Person/Group/Resource, and if so is it related to Email?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow you. There will be some relation between the parent tables such as a Resource can be owned by a person (or many persons). Email is more an attribute that each of the parent table items can have.

Answer (score 3):

This is a core part of SQL.  In a proper relational design, you don't relate email addresess to perosns, groups, or resources -- you relate the persons, groups, and resources TO the email.

So, with an email table of:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblEmail (
  emailID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(500)
)
```

If you only need one email per entity, you would just insert an `emailID` on each of the other fields that model something that may need an email.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblPerson
ADD emailID int REFERENCES dbo.tblEmail(emailID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblGroup
ADD emailID int REFERENCES dbo.tblEmail(emailID);

ALTER TABLE dbo.tblResource
ADD emailID int REFERENCES dbo.tblEmail(emailID);
```

If you need *multiple* email addresses per entity, you need to insert an additional table, to interpolate the set of email addresses to a particular address.  (I wouldn't do this unless you have a technical reason to handle the addresses individually, such as a bulk-email system where you want to avoid duplicates if someone uses the same email for their own use and their organization's use.)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblEmail (
  emailID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblEmailAddress (
  eAddrID IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  eAddr varchar(500)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.tblEmailSet (
  emailID int REFERENCES dbo.tblEmail(emailID),
  eAddrID int REFERENCES dbo.tblEmailAddresses(eAddrID),
)
```

In order to, say, return a list of all emails to any Person, Group, or Resource named "Smith", you'd run the query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.eAddr
FROM (
  SELECT emailID FROM dbo.tblPerson WHERE Name = 'Smith'
  UNION
  SELECT emailID FROM dbo.tblGroup WHERE Name = 'Smith'
  UNION
  SELECT emailID FROM dbo.tblResource WHERE Name = 'Smith'
) AS PGR
INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmailSet AS S
  ON PGR.emailID = S.emailID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblEmailAddress AS A
  ON S.eAddrID = A.eAddrID
```

That ugly `UNION`, btw, is one of the reasons why you really don't want to do this unless you have a technical need to retrieve the data uniquely.  While I've done this sort of many-to-many-to-many join on occasion, in this particular instance it's kind of a "code smell" and an indicator that instead of tracking "People", "Groups", and "Resources", you should be tracking "Contacts" with a "type" indicator to tell if a contact is a Person, a  Group, or a Resource.

(Or maybe you never need to grab a bunch of email addresses, and just want a single table of emails you can check for whitelisting...)

Comment: And, as a nitpick that drives me crazy -- don't use hungariation notation for database names!  Sure, "dbo.tblGroup" is a table **NOW**, but if it's just "dbo.Group" you can refactor it as a View or TBF down the road if appropriate, without mangling your names.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This only allows me to have a single email address per person/group/resource. I need to be able to have many email addresses per.

Answer (score 2):

While it may be tempting to try and use a single email table with a `ParentType` (Person/Group/Resource) and `ParentID`, this is dangerous and means you can't have the relationship defined in SQL (unless there's some feature I'm unaware of?).

If you want to have referential integrity in SQL you really need to create 3 tables, one for each parent table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PersonEmail (
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PersonID int,
    EmailAddress varchar(500)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.GroupEmail (
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    GroupID int,
    EmailAddress varchar(500)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ResourceEmail (
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ResourceID int,
    EmailAddress varchar(500)
)
```

If you think you might extend your Email table to later include a DisplayName, and perhaps a BounceCount and others, create a table for Email and create many-to-many join tables to link them to Person/Group/Resource.

Be aware that edits might impact multiple links, you'll have to decide how you want to handle that.

Comment: The OP specified using a single `tblEmail`. Just create the three tables as cross-references between the Person/Group/Resource tables and the Email table and it should meet their requirement. It does beg the question of handling shared or recurring email addresses.

Comment: @HABO as mentioned in my remarks after the SQL script, having a single `tblEmail` is an option, but would require 3 join tables (many-to-many). I would prefer that option myself to allow for future growth of the Email table, but presented a simpler option in the first part of my answer.

Comment: So, this was a thought of mine but it had wanted a single table. This is simple and sound and I could join the separate email tables in a view. The issue will be possible duplicate emails but I can handle that in code. I may go this route if I reorganize my parent tables a bit, perhaps organize by system rather than role.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have possibly multiple Emails per Person/Group/Resource, and you want all those emails in one table, am I correct ?

To do that,  I would create a table dbo.EmailAddress such as this :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailAddress 
(
   EmailID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   ,EmailAddress VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL

   CONSTRAINT UK_EmailAddress UNIQUE(EmailAddress) --to ensure that you never insert twice the same email address
)
```

Then I would create the relation between your Person/Group/Resource and you emails using another table :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailAddressParentXRef
(
    EmailID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.EmailAddress(EmailID)
    ,ParentTypeID INT NOT NULL
    ,PersonID INT NULL REFERENCES dbo.tblPerson(PersonID)
    ,GroupID INT NULL REFERENCES dbo.tblGroup(GroupID)
    ,ResourceID INT NULL REFERENCES dbo.tblResource(ResourceID)

    CONSTRAINT UK_EmailID_ParentTypeID UNIQUE(EmailID,ParentTypeID) --to make sure you don't put the same EmailID for the same type of Parent (e.g. EmailID=12 twice for an Account)
)
```

There you would have referential integrity + some checks to avoid duplicates when you load data. Note that I didn't put a check to make sure you actually fill in either the PersonID, GroupID or ResourceID. This can be added in different ways, but if you understand the principle of this table, you shouldn't load any line without those references (or they will just be useless).

A lot more checks can be added based on this, to take care of every type of duplication/error you might create when loading the data, but you get the point.

Comment: The schema of your XRef table would suggest that adding a link between something like "board.room@mycompany.com" and Resource "Board Room" would require that I must also link it to a Person and a Group (since they don't allow NULL), but such an email would possibly have no Person/Group.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. However, as Timothy mentioned, you can't have FKs to all three of the parent tables. The same email would never exist in all three tables. Remove the constraint and allow NULLs then it would work, just no integrity on the SQL level.

Comment: You guys are right, those should be NULLable, and I thought I had corrected that, so my mistake.
You can still  keep the Fks though, as they just force any value (but not NULLs) to be contained by the table they reference. This way you still have the integrity you wanted (or maybe I am missing something ?).